# void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. how to remove this kind of messages

Tags: iphone

I am loading the data in the NSdata before viewdidload

I got following message

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
If you were not using the touch screen for this entire interval (which can prolong this wait), please file a bug.
```

Comment: Hi I have same issue ..have you found any solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844/

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest not doing something on your main thread which will take 10 seconds at startup.  Show some UI, use a background thread to load large data sets.

Comment: same error but this is not working for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374844/